# toolbar.getChildCount() returns 0

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, viewgroup

I am trying to change the font of my application title. In order to do this, I decided to traverse through the toolbar, find the title TextView and then set the typeface.

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView title = null;
    View child = null;
    for(int i=0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++){
        child = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
        if(child instanceof TextView){
            title = (TextView) child;
            break;
        }
    }
    Typeface logoFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/font.ttf");
    if(title!=null){
        title.setTypeface(logoFont);
    }
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

But toolbar.getChildCount() is returning 0. Toolbar doesn't seem to have any children. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Make your toolbar visible before you call `getChildCount()` .

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getChildAt` and `getChildCount` after `setSupportActionBar`.